# Difference between Normal Map and collections.synchronizedmap

Tags: java, collections

In some android open source code I found

```
 private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new
 WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
```

can any one explain me difference between Normal `Map` and `collections.synchronizedmap`

Comment: "synchronized" means "thread safe". If that doesn't help you, I suggest you read up on multithreading in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular Map implementations in java.util package are not thread safe. This means that if multiple threads are doing `get()` or `put()` operations on the same Map, it may result in race conditions or inconsistent data in the Map.

To use an existing Map in a multi-threaded environment, you can get a synchronized instance of the same by calling `Collections.synchronizedMap()`. On such instances, most of the methods like `get()`, `put` and `keyset()` are synchronized and can be safely used concurrently.

For more information on this, refer to
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)

Answer (score 1):

There is no normal Map. You cannot create just a Map (new Map() wont compile). Map is a common interface to access data in different kinds of maps (hashMap, synchronizedMap, WeakHashMap...). Read any Java book, Collections chapter.

Using Map as common interface allows you to write data manipulation algorinthms which will work for all types of Map implementations. So you can switch implementation (maybe you realized that you need synchronized map here and not just HashMap) and your code will work.

synchronizedMap is just a wrapper. It wraps all data access functions of underlying Map and makes them thread safe.

In your case you have WeakHashMap which is "real" map. WeakHashMap defines how map stores data (it uses hashes for keys and weakRefences for values). Then you wrap it in synchronizedMap which makes your map thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection(java.util.Collection)

A synchronized map is a thread-safe map, meaning that read/write operations are thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

We are using "Synchronized" to ensure that two concurrently-executing threads or processes do not execute specific portions of a program at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.synchronizedMap` pretty much wraps your Map object so that every call to map methods is synchronized, meaning only one thread at a time can update or query the map.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.synchronizedMap()` is a very poor way to achieve thread safety. It takes a lock on each method, so at most one thread can access your map. It doesn't have support for atomic operations as compare-and-set. Also you have to remember to synchronize on the object yourself when iterating over the keys/values or else it looses all of it's magic.

Look at `ConcurrentHashMap`, if you need a thread-safe `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

**Collections** utility class provides static methods to creat thread safe collection(List, Set, Queue, Map ). 
So to convert any thread unsafe collection into a thread safe one; you call synchronized method on Collections and then pass your collection as parameter.

A thread safe collection can be accessed by only one thread at a time.

URL : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html